# in android compose pointerInput how can i use the key parameter

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the code like below.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainCompose(trigger: Int) {
    var trigger by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val onDrag = { trigger += 1 }
    MyPointInput(trigger = trigger, onDrag)
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyPointInput(trigger: Int, onDrag: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Green)
        .size(300.dp)
        .pointerInput(trigger) {
            var a = 0
            detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                println("trigger: $trigger with $a")
                a += 1
                onDrag()
            }
        })
}
```

When i start drag  i can see the number in console 1, 2, 3 ....

but if the trigger number is changed, printing stop and do not start again.

In document, it said

> Specifying the captured value as a key parameter will cause block to
> cancel and restart from the beginning if the value changes:

why my code didn't restart?

Comment: Would you mind posting how you update trigger. Using a mutableStateOf to trigger recomposition on MyPointerInput should restart block inside Modifier.pointerInput. I use it in many ways and in many libraries. It works exactly as described like in this for instance. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Extended-Gestures. Modifier.pointerInput uses LaunchedEffect(key){block()} under the hood and works exactly as LaunchedEffect key changes occur

Comment: I don't know it is right example(or use) but updated the code @Thracian

Answer (score 1):

If the useage is as in question you are shadowing parameter of `MainCompose(trigger: Int)`
only `var trigger by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }` is used if you want to reset trigger value to value from parameter you can update it as

```
@Composable
fun MainCompose(initialValue: Int) {
    var trigger by remember(initialValue) { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    val onDrag = { trigger += 1 }
    Text("Trigger: $trigger")
    MyPointInput(trigger = trigger, onDrag)
}
```

by changing to this you will update trigger on every onDrag invocation and reset to value that is sent from function that calls `MainCompose` with `initialValue` param.

You might also want to reset Modiifer.pointerInput() every time initialValue changes instead of trigger itself as

```
MyPointInput(trigger = initialValue, onDrag)
```

this will only reset when new value is sent via MainCompose. Using trigger as param changes the moment trigger is updated and causing previous one to be discarded immediately, of course assuming this is not intended behavior.

Output will be as

[image]

With implementation below

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {

    var value by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    Column() {

        MainCompose(value)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Button(onClick = {
            value++
        }) {
            Text(text = "Click")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainCompose(initialValue: Int) {
    var trigger by remember(initialValue) { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    val onDrag = { trigger += 1 }
    Text("Trigger: $trigger")
    MyPointInput(trigger = initialValue, onDrag)
}

@Composable
fun MyPointInput(trigger: Int, onDrag: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Green)
        .size(300.dp)
        .pointerInput(trigger) {
            var a = 0
            detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                println("trigger: $trigger with $a")
                a += 1
                onDrag()
            }
        })
}
```

And some of the logs as

```
 I  trigger: 2 with 34
 I  trigger: 2 with 35
 I  trigger: 2 with 36
 I  trigger: 3 with 0
 I  trigger: 3 with 1
 I  trigger: 3 with 2
 I  trigger: 3 with 3
 I  trigger: 3 with 4
 I  trigger: 3 with 5
 I  trigger: 3 with 6
 I  trigger: 3 with 7
 I  trigger: 3 with 8
 I  trigger: 3 with 9
 I  trigger: 3 with 10
 I  trigger: 3 with 11
 I  trigger: 3 with 12
 I  trigger: 3 with 13
 I  trigger: 3 with 14
 I  trigger: 3 with 15
 I  trigger: 3 with 16
 I  trigger: 3 with 17
 I  trigger: 3 with 18
 I  trigger: 3 with 19
 I  trigger: 3 with 20
 I  trigger: 3 with 21
 I  trigger: 3 with 22
 I  trigger: 3 with 23
 I  trigger: 3 with 24
 I  trigger: 3 with 25
 I  trigger: 3 with 26
 I  trigger: 3 with 27
 I  trigger: 3 with 28
 I  trigger: 3 with 29
 I  trigger: 3 with 30
 I  trigger: 3 with 31
 I  trigger: 3 with 32
 I  trigger: 3 with 33
 I  trigger: 3 with 34
 I  trigger: 3 with 35
 I  trigger: 3 with 36
 I  trigger: 3 with 37
 I  trigger: 3 with 38
 I  trigger: 4 with 0
 I  trigger: 4 with 1
 I  trigger: 4 with 2
 I  trigger: 4 with 3
 I  trigger: 4 with 4
 I  trigger: 4 with 5
 I  trigger: 4 with 6
 I  trigger: 4 with 7
 I  trigger: 4 with 8
 I  trigger: 4 with 9
 I  trigger: 4 with 10
 I  trigger: 4 with 11
 I  trigger: 4 with 12
 I  trigger: 4 with 13
 I  trigger: 4 with 14
 I  trigger: 4 with 15
 I  trigger: 4 with 16
 I  trigger: 4 with 17
 I  trigger: 4 with 18
 I  trigger: 4 with 19
 I  trigger: 4 with 20
 I  trigger: 4 with 21
 I  trigger: 4 with 22
 I  trigger: 4 with 23
```

Comment: Yes it looks like a trick and maybe it is not intended behavior. because it use remember's cache and  in your code trigger is not changed. my point in the question, what is the true meaning of restart when key is changed

Comment: It's not a trick. It's how it works. Reseting it means re-launching LaunchedEffect inside the remember. By updating key you trigger a block you send to LaunchedEffect. As you can see in the logs. You send new lambda, onDrag() on every time you update LaunchedEffect. These create closures, a block that does updates what's currently inside it, until you restart it